# What is wrong in this code? (v1)

Tags: java

I got this exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver).
 But this code work in other program.
The problem in connection.

```
   public Connection conect(){
               Connection con= null;
            try {  
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
                "databaseName=hotel;user=jps;password=123;";
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
                System.out.println( cE.toString());
            }
               return con ;
        }
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your JDBC library in not in the CLASSPATH, so Java cannot find the `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` class.

You code is correct, but you should look for the JDBC library and include it when you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `jtds` driver jar from [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/), and it to your Java classpath.